public ip for a docker pod inside ec2
I have a k8s cluster and docker pod runs in a ec2. I am trying to assign elastic ip to an ec2 instance so docker container running inside the ec2 will have that fixed ip address. We consume external system's service they need to know from what ip we make calls to their system so they can white list our ip. For this I am trying to use elastic ip. I did assign elastic ip to the instance but still when I do curl https://2ip.io/ to the outside internet to know my public ip I see completely different ip address that elastic ip I assigned.
Appreciate any help
run curl https://2ip.io/ inside the container and I expect elastic ip

"We consume external system's service they need to know from what ip we make calls to their system so they can white list our ip." - You can do this with a NAT gateway without assigning a public IP to the instance.
